# Join two files based on Column with delimited values using SQL quotes in Spark

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

SQL/spark-sql
I have two files User and look up. Need to join the two with SQL queries only. Please help me in this regard.
Role id is combination of multiple roles.in user files roles Order can be different from role file.
**Edit1**: delimited values may not be in same order like for 432
User file
**Edit2**: The below one solved in spark sql
select * from User_file inner join Role_file on sort_array(split(lower(Role),','))=sort_array(split(lower(Role),','))

```
+----+-----------------+
|User|             role|
+----+-----------------+
| 123|      role1,role2|
| 324|            role1|
| 432|role2,role1,role3|
+----+-----------------+
```

Role file

Role, role id

```
+-----------------+-------+
|             Role|role_id|
+-----------------+-------+
|            Role1|      1|
|            Role2|      2|
|            Role3|      3|
|      Role1,role2|      4|
|role1,role2,role3|   5   |
+-----------------+-------+
```

Output file should be

```
+----+-----------------+------+
|User|             role|roleid|
+----+-----------------+------+
| 123|      role1,role2|     4|
| 324|            role1|     1|
| 432|role1,role2,role3|     5|
+----+-----------------+------+
```

Comment: Fix your data model!  Don't store multiple values in a single column.

Answer (score 1):

select u.userid, u.role, r.roleid
from user_file u
inner join role_file r on u.role = r.role

The role data in user file can be updated to have roles in sorted order:

with nuser_file as
(
select userid, value
from user_file
cross apply string_split(role, ",")
),
nnuser_file as
(
select userid, string_agg(value, ",") within group (order by value asc) as role
from nuser_file
group by userid
)

update user_file
set role = b.role
from user_file a
inner join nnuser_file b on a.userid = b.userid
and a.role != b.role

Comment: for user id 432 role id value will not match as the user file has different order of role id's.

Comment: @user3106218 . . . It matches in the data you have provided.  If you have another question, then ask it as a *new* question.

Comment: @user3106218 Posted code to update data in user file in sorted order.

Answer (score 0):

> Solution with Scala Code

```
scala> var test2 = spark.createDataFrame(Seq((123,"role1,role2"),(324,"role1"),(432,"role2,role1,role3"))).toDF("user","role")
scala> var test3  =spark.createDataFrame(Seq(("role1",1),("role2",2),("role3",3),("role1,role2",4),("role2,role1,role3",5))).toDF("role","role_id")
scala> test2.join(test3,Seq("role")).show()

+-----------------+----+-------+
|             role|user|role_id|
+-----------------+----+-------+
|            role1| 324|      1|
|      role1,role2| 123|      4|
|role2,role1,role3| 432|      5|
+-----------------+----+-------+
```

I think that's what you are looking for. let me know if you have more queries related to this. HAppy HAdoop